# Complex SQL query. At least for me

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to pull invoice data from my database based on a PatientID. I am trying to figure out which invoices belong to which patient. Here is the important parts of my structure.

Invoices Table

```
InvoiceNumber | DateInvoice | DueDate | StudyID | TypeInvoice
```

Patients Table

```
FirstName | LastName | PatientID
```

InvoiceFields

```
id | InvoiceNumber | PatientID |
```

I need make a query that lists the invoice table data based upon a PatientID. Below is the query that I attempted, but got no where with. Thank you for your time.

```
SELECT    Distinct
          invoicefields.InvoiceNumber,
          invoices.DateInvoice
FROM      `invoices`, `patients`, `invoicefields`
WHERE     invoicefields.PatientID = patients.PatientID
          and invoicefields.InvoiceNumber = invoicefields.InvoiceNumber
GROUP BY  invoicefields.InvoiceNumber
```

Comment: Do you want to go Invoice to Patient or Patient to Invoice?

Comment: In your schema, one invoice can have items for multiple patients. Is this true in the domain (e.g., multiple members of one family with the same insurance)?

Comment: njk, I need to supply the query with a patient id and it give me the data in the invoice table.

Comment: Post an example of what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT InvT.InvoiceNumber, InvT.DateInvoice
FROM InvoiceTable InvT
INNER JOIN InvoiceFields InvF ON InvF.InvoiceNumber = InvT.InvoiceNumber AND InvF.PatientID = @PatientID
```

So pretty much since you only need data from the InvoiceTable and you indicate you have the PatientID.  I propose you just join to the Cross Reference table InvoiceFields and use the PatientID column in that query to filter it down to what you need.  I had a more complex example using an exist before I realized you didn't need anything from Patients.

You could use this if you need information on the Patient as well (Just put the needed columns in the Select)

```
SELECT InvT.InvoiceNumber, InvT.DateInvoice
FROM InvoiceTable InvT
INNER JOIN InvoiceFields InvF ON InvF.InvoiceNumber = InvT.InvoiceNumber AND InvF.PatientID = @PatientID
INNER JOIN Patient Pat ON Pat.PatientID = InvF.PatientID
```

You can put the @PatientID portion on the join for either Patient or InvoiceFields.  There really shouldn't be a performance difference between either way if you indexes are right.

The Response to the Below Comment but where I can show it cleaner:

```
SELECT  IT.InvoiceNumber
       ,IT.DateInvoice
FROM    InvoiceTable InvT
WHERE   EXISTS (SELECT  InvF.PatientID
                FROM    InvoiceFields InvF
                WHERE   InvF.InvoiceNumber = InvT.InvoiceNumber
                AND InvF.PatientID = @PatientID)
```

This will return all the rows for the patient from InvoiceTable and if InvoiceNumber is Unique will not have any duplicates. Though this way you only have access to InvoiceTable to return Data from.  If you only want one put a TOP 1 on it:

```
SELECT  TOP 1 IT.InvoiceNumber
       ,IT.DateInvoice
FROM    InvoiceTable InvT
WHERE   EXISTS (SELECT  InvF.PatientID
                FROM    InvoiceFields InvF
                WHERE   InvF.InvoiceNumber = InvT.InvoiceNumber
                AND InvF.PatientID = @PatientID)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but all i get is: MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows).

Comment: nvm the first comment, I derped hard there, but i still have one issue. this is the same comment as below.   This query works, but the invoicefields can have multiple invoice numbers. This table lists the inside fields for the invoice which have the patient number in it. I need to display 1 invoice number and the data that is in that invoice. There can also be more than 1 invoice they are involved in. My goal is to not show the same invoice twice in the query.

Comment: A little confused unless you have multiple rows in your cross reference table that have the same PatientID and InvoiceNumber. Are there more rows to the cross reference table? Regardless you can abstract all that away by: SELECT IT.InvoiceNumber, IT.DateInvoice FROM InvoiceTable InvT WHERE EXISTS (SELECT InvF.PatientID FROM InvoiceFields InvF WHERE InvF.InvoiceNumber = InvT.InvoiceNumber AND InvF.PatientID = @PatientID) Which pretty much just says Hey, Is this guy in the sub query. If Invoice Number isn't Unique in InvoiceTable, which if it is the primary key it should be, put a Top 1 on it

Comment: Not sure. I'm glad that helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * from invoices i
inner join invoicefields iFld
    on i.invoiceNumber = iFld.invoiceNumber
inner join patients p
    on iFld.patientID = p.patientID
    and p.patientID = 1235125
```

This should get you started in the right direction at least.  I'm not sure what columns you wanted to return and/or if there's any nulls in the tables.  Nulls will affect which rows are returned

Comment: This query works, but the invoicefields can have multiple invoice numbers. This table lists the inside fields for the invoice which have the patient number in it. I need to display 1 invoice number and the data that is in that invoice. There can also be more than 1 invoice they are involved in. My goal is to not show the same invoice twice in the query.

Comment: @Kevin - If it works, but you need distinct, add a `GROUP BY`.  Provide the columns you want shown and sample desired output for more specific answers.